# Image with negative right, makes unwanted horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to hide an image to the right with a right positioning of -100%. When i apply the negative right, the image go all the way to the right and create a blank horizontal space where the image is visible. When i do the same thing on the left side image, the image is hidden correctly.

I need to hide the image with a transition from right 0 to right -100% without creating horizontal scroll in the page

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

}

.image-left {
  width: 75%;
  weight: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
}

.image-right {
 width: 76%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 right:-100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="image-left" src="DISRUPTHINK-LOGO-PROCESO-021800.png" alt="">


<img class="image-right" src="DISRUPTHINK-LOGO-PROCESO-03-1800.png" alt="">
```

Im using scroll magic to open an image when scrolling, hidding the left part with negative left, and the right with negative right but i need the negative part hidden without the page scrolling horizontal to the right.

Comment: "I need to hide the image with a transition from right 0 to right -100% without creating horizontal scroll in the page" - Why? Just do visibility: hidden

Comment: because is a transition sliding effect

Comment: Place your image inside the container, fixed width/height and css rule `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: If it doesnt matter, hiding stuff *left* of the body doesnt give you extra scrolling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick working example below. Essentially you need to set `overflow: hidden;` to `html, body` so that when your images overflow the width of their container (which is set to `100%`), the container won't expand and have a scrollbar.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".image-right").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-right {
  width: 76%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  transition: right .4s ease;
  right:-100%;
}

.show {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image-right" src="http://placekitten.com/500/800" alt="">

<button type="button">click to show image</button>
```

Comment: I can scroll sideways if I press my scrollwheel and move it to the right (which is how I always scroll)